# How to implement sprite kit blur effect without drop of fps?

Tags: ios, filter, sprite, blur

I'm trying to make blur effect during the game with sprite kit :

```
let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius" : NSNumber(value:1.0)])!
scene!.filter = filter
self.filter = filter
self.shouldEnableEffects = true
```

however, this leads to significant drop of fps. Is there any proper way how to make this effect without losing playability?